# get set members value in REDIS

Tags: redis

Suppose i have 3 users . I store these 3 users in redis by -

```
SET user1 " 'name': 'a', 'age' : 1 "
SET user2 " 'name': 'b', 'age' : 2 "
SET user3 " 'name': 'c', 'age' : 3 "
```

- `user1` and `user2` are the member of a group called `group1`
- `user2` and `user3` are group member of `group2`

if i use `SMEMBERS family` then i'll get only member list

```
SMEMBERS group1

1) "user1"
2) "user2"
```

But i want the values of those keys. I can use `hash family`, but if i use hash i won't be able to access `user1` without mentioning it's group name. what i meant is that, if i want the value of `user1` i have to write `hget group1 user1`, but it is not always possible to know the group name .

What i really want is more like a mixer of `MGET` & `SMEMBERS`

```
GET user1

1) " 'name': 'a', 'age' : 1 "

GET group1

1) " 'name': 'b', 'age' : 2 "
2) " 'name': 'c', 'age' : 3 "
```

Is there any way to do that

Answer (score 0):

There is no one built-in data structure to solve your problem in redis. It doesn't work like RDBMs to putting the data into one table and querying on different columns. You need to maintain multiple keys to achieve your different queries. You may use both `hash`/`set` to keep track of users and groups. Another option would be `hash`/`hash`.

- `hash`/`set` version (`sets` provide uniqueness of the groups)

```
127.0.0.1:6379> hset user:1 name 'a' age 1
(integer) 2
127.0.0.1:6379> hset user:2 name 'b' age 2
(integer) 2
127.0.0.1:6379> hset user:3 name 'c' age 3
(integer) 2
127.0.0.1:6379> hgetall user:2
1) "name"
2) "b"
3) "age"
4) "2"
127.0.0.1:6379> sadd group1 user:1 user:2
(integer) 2
127.0.0.1:6379> smembers group1
1) "user:1"
2) "user:2"
127.0.0.1:6379>
```

- `hash`/`hash` version (`hash fields` provide uniqueness of the groups)

```
127.0.0.1:6379> hset user:1 name 'a' age 1
(integer) 2
127.0.0.1:6379> hset user:2 name 'b' age 2
(integer) 2
127.0.0.1:6379> hset user:3 name 'c' age 3
(integer) 2
127.0.0.1:6379> hset group1 user:1 1 user:2 1
(integer) 2
127.0.0.1:6379> hkeys group1
1) "user:1"
2) "user:2"
127.0.0.1:6379>
```

Answer (score 0):

To simply answer the question: `SORT group1 BY nosort GET *`

Read about SORT here: https://redis.io/commands/sort/

> When the elements are not sorted, complexity is O(N).

Setup

```
SET user1 " 'name': 'a', 'age' : 1 "
SET user2 " 'name': 'b', 'age' : 2 "
SET user3 " 'name': 'c', 'age' : 3 "
sadd group1 user1 user2
```

Result

```
> SORT group1 BY nosort GET *
1) " 'name': 'b', 'age' : 2 "
2) " 'name': 'a', 'age' : 1 "
```